# converting string to number in powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to convert a string to a 2 decimal place value

I have a script that has a line of code which is

```
(get-mailboxdatabase xxx -status).databasesize
```

This returns the size something like 
    1.008 GB (1,082,195,968 bytes)

I want to be able to convert this to a number (1.008) and can't work out how to do it.

I know about ToGB() but that only works when running the script from EMS.

I need to be able to run the script in Powershell and not EMS as the script does other things.

How do I convert the value to a number?

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using implicit remoting (it sounds like you are), that's going to be a [string], so you'll need to use string methods.

```
'1.008 GB (1,082,195,968 bytes)' -replace '^([0-9.]+).+','$1'
1.008
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Many thanks, I spent most of the day searching for that. is there a website that explains what is being done after the -replace?

Comment: Try `help about_Comparison_Operators` and `help about_Regular_Expressions`.

Comment: How could I alter this so it displayed the bytes value(1,082,195,968 bytes) as a number(1082195968)

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, just make a cast and divide with 1GB.

```
PS C:\> [int]"1082195968"/1GB
1,00787353515625
```

[image]

Or in your case

```
([int](get-mailboxdatabase xxx -status).databasesize)/1GB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert numbers to the various number types using standard .NET framework types and conversions. For example:

```
> $var = [decimal]::Parse("1.008")
> $var.GetType().Name
Decimal
```

Extracting just that portion of the string from the input is a separate issue, and it's hard to tell from your question which is giving you trouble. To get just the number, you might use something like this:

```
$input = (get-mailboxdatabase xxx -status).databasesize
$strSize = $input.Split(' ')[0]
```

Or you can use a regular expression. It all depends on how variable your size is.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$val= (get-mailboxdatabase xxx -status).databasesize
[decimal]([regex]::Match( $val, '(^.+)GB' )).groups[1].value
```